# VS2008 not picking up recently added web controls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Has anyone had experience with VS2008 incorrectly identifying variables in the code-behind as not being defined on the .aspx page?  How was this resolved?  The page is executing properly without any runtime or compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.  Closing and re-opening the document in question seems to have resolved the problem.   Anyone watch "The IT Crowd"?  ... haha.  "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"   Seems to solve everything.

Comment: This is a common issue with Visual Studio.  Closing and re-opening the file and/or solution is the recommended solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer to my question here: [Web site reports xxx does not exist in current context after upgrade to VS2008 Sp1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658490/web-site-reports-xxx-does-not-exist-in-current-context-after-upgrade-to-vs2008-sp/658681#658681)

There is a hotfix for this if your getting the same issue I was.